# MPandroidchart - i want to add more point when the user scrolls up or down or right or left

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart, cartesian-coordinates

Initially the graph goes from -10 to 10 but i want that when the user scrolls right the values are evaluated and the graph "grows". Is there any listeners for that.
I meant that when the user scrolls to the right then i add more points as for function, there is always a value of y for an x. The graph keep constructing itself when the user scrolls up down right or left.

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by **values are evaluated**.

Comment: I edited the question.@AyushBansal

Comment: Try using ChartGesture listener . Here's the link                   https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart#gesture-callbacks

Comment: can u please add some demo code thx.

Comment: and can u plz tell me how can i see if the user has reached the end.

Comment: You want to add points when user scrolls or points are being added irrespective or user scrolling.....

Comment: Initially the points are from -10 to 10 so when user scrolls to the right of 10 then  it does not scroll as there is no data i want that the points are evaluated after the end is reached so that user can scroll to any point he wants and therefore reducinng the memory consumption as well as giving user the full control.

Answer (score 4):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        linechart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        new Random(0).nextInt();
        linechart.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(true);
        linechart.setScaleEnabled(true);
        linechart.setPinchZoom(true);
        linechart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
        linechart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        linechart.setOnChartGestureListener(new GestureListener());

        LineData lineData = new LineData();
        lineData.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        linechart.setData(lineData);

        Legend legend = linechart.getLegend();
        legend.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.LINE);
        legend.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        XAxis xaxis = linechart.getXAxis();
        xaxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
        xaxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        xaxis.setTextSize(15f);
        xaxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        YAxis yaxis = linechart.getAxisLeft();
        yaxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        yaxis.setTextSize(15f);
        yaxis = linechart.getAxisRight();
        yaxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        yaxis.setTextSize(15f);
        linechart.invalidate();
    }

    private void addEntry(int number) {
        data = linechart.getData();

        if (data != null)
        {
            ILineDataSet set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);

            if (set == null) {
                set = createSet();
                data.addDataSet(set);
            }
            data.addEntry(new Entry(data.getDataSetByIndex(0).getEntryCount(), number), 0);
            data.notifyDataChanged();
            linechart.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }

    private LineDataSet createSet() {

        LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(null, "");
        set.setCubicIntensity(0.0f);
        set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
        set.setColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
        set.setCircleColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
        set.setDrawValues(false);
        set.setLineWidth(2f);
        set.setCircleSize(4f);
        set.setFillAlpha(65);
        set.disableDashedLine();
        return set;

    }
    class GestureListener implements OnChartGestureListener {

        @Override
        public void onChartGestureStart(MotionEvent me, ChartTouchListener.ChartGesture lastPerformedGesture) {

            addEntry(//add your entries here);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChartGestureEnd(MotionEvent me, ChartTouchListener.ChartGesture lastPerformedGesture) {
            linechart.moveViewToX(data.getEntryCount());

        }

        @Override
        public void onChartLongPressed(MotionEvent me) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChartDoubleTapped(MotionEvent me) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChartSingleTapped(MotionEvent me) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChartFling(MotionEvent me1, MotionEvent me2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChartScale(MotionEvent me, float scaleX, float scaleY) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChartTranslate(MotionEvent me, float dX, float dY) {

        }
    }
```

Try this out

Comment: Thx for ur time i will try it at night . And is there any way that i can delete a "line" between two points in a linedataset , i am asking this because when drawing the graph of 1/x a line is drawn between the last point behind the y axis and the first point after the y axis, it is not correct . And how can i detect whether the points are aproaching infinity as in case of graph of tanx . All other graphs are drawing perfectly. Thx for ur help.

Comment: and can i remove a legend of a particular linedataset ?

Comment: You can remove Legend. From what i know Legend is specified for a chart and not for a linedataset. If I am wrong please provide a link so I can update myself :)

Comment: if the above code is not giving desired effect , please let me know